# C# Switch Statement Using Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement

I have to write a program that prompts the user for a menu choice using Method.

I tried to write something but I failed. :,(

Here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Choose a Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Calculate Area");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Calculate Volume");
        Console.WriteLine("3: Calculate Surface Area");
        Console.WriteLine("0: Exit the program");

        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(calculateTotal(number));


    }

    public static int calculateTotal(int number)
    {


        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Calculate Area");
                Console.Write("Input Length\t");
                int L1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input Width\t");
                int W1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Area is\t");
                Console.WriteLine(L1 * W1);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("2: Calculate Volume");
                Console.Write("Input Length\t");
                int L2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input Width\t");
                int W2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input Height\t");
                int H2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Volume is\t");
                Console.WriteLine(L2 * W2 * H2);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("3: Calculate Surface Area");
                Console.Write("Input Length\t");
                int L3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input Width\t");
                int W3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Surface Area is\t");
                Console.WriteLine(L3 * W3 * 2);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Exit the program now");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid Choice");
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

And here is my problem

['Program.calculateTotal(int)':not all code paths return a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZnv.jpg)

I am a super beginner in programming so
Could you help me to find a problem please?

Comment: Since _none_ of the code paths in the `calculateTotal()` method return a value, the compiler error you are getting is unsurprising. Why not just make the method return `void` instead of `int`? (To do that, you will of course need to remove the last `Console.WriteLine()` in your `Main()` method, calling the `calculateTotal()` method directly without trying to use its return value.)

Comment: Thanks a million!!!!!!!!!